# Creating numpy functions and converting to tensor

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, numpy-ufunc

I am trying to create function using numpy something like f=(x-a1)^2+(y-a2)^2+a3

Where a1,a2,a3 are random generated numbers and x,y are parameters.

But I cant work with it, I want to find f(0,0) where [0,0] is [x,y] and [a1,a2,a3] were set before,but my code doesnt work.
And then I want to convert this function to tensorflow tensor.Here is my code, string with "##" dont work.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from random import random, seed
import numpy as np


def mypolyval(x, min_point, min_value):
    res = min_value
    for i in range(len(min_point)):
        res += (x[i] - min_point[i]) ** 2
    return res


class FunGen:
    def __init__(self, dim, n):
        self.dim = dim
        self.n = n
        self.functions = []
        self.x = []

    def c2(self):
        seed(10)
        for _ in range(self.n):
            min_point = [random() for _ in range(self.dim)]
            min_value = random()
            f = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['x'])

            ##print(f(x=np.array([0, 0]), min_point=min_point, min_value=min_value))
            self.functions.append((f, min_point, min_value))
        return self.functions


functions = FunGen(2, 1).c2()
for i in functions:
    print(type(i[0]))
    f=i[0]
   ## print(f(x=[0, 0], min_value=i[1], min_point=i[2]))
    ##a=tf.convert_to_tensor(f,dtype=np.float32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to tensorflow. The line

```
min_point = [random() for _ in range(self.dim)]
```

creates a list and lists don't have the `.size()` property.

You can turn it into a numpy array using `min_point = np.array([random() for _ in range(self.dim)]))`, then the `.size()` will work.

Or if you want to stick to the list use `for i in range(len(min_point))`, which calculates the length of a list.

Also you need to add `min_point` and `min_value` them to the excluded list:

```
from random import random, seed
import numpy as np


def mypolyval(x, min_point, min_value):

    print('x', x)
    print('min_point', min_point)
    print('min_value', min_value)
    res = min_value
    for i in range(len(min_point)):
        res += (x[i] - min_point[i]) ** 2
    return res


class FunGen:
    def __init__(self, dim, n):
        self.dim = dim
        self.n = n
        self.functions = []
        self.x = []

    def c2(self):
        seed(10)
        for _ in range(self.n):
            min_point = [random() for _ in range(self.dim)]
            min_value = random()
            f = np.vectorize(mypolyval, excluded=['x', 'min_point', 'min_value'])
            #print(f(x=[0, 0], min_value=min_value, min_point=min_point))
            self.functions.append((f, min_point, min_value))
        return self.functions


functions = FunGen(2, 1).c2()
for i in functions:
    print(type(i[0]))
    print(i)
    f=i[0]
    print(f(x=[0, 0], min_value=i[2], min_point=i[1]))
```

Comment: Answer adjusted.

Comment: I changed size to len in function u told,its working better now ,but I am also having problems  with 2 strings .which are comments,they are dont work.
          
  print(f(x=[0, 0], min_value=min_value, min_point=min_point))

This is error:

   for i in range(len(min_point)):
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()

Comment: You have to remove the `.size()`, in your code above it is still there.

Comment: No, keep the `len()` and remove `.size()`

Comment: Ok, got it now. You flipped the parameters `self.functions.append((f, min_point, min_value))`. Here `min_point` is second. But when you call it `print(f(x=[0, 0], min_value=i[1], min_point=i[2]))` then `i[1]` is `min_value`.

Comment: Yes,I see,changed already,but problem is before append.cause i m trying to calc F(0,0) before appending,just after vectorize

Comment: I added the variables to the exclude list, see answer above.

Comment: Got it,didnt know that i need to add all executed,big thanks

Comment: But I am not sure, maybe @Nicolas' approach is the cleaner solution.

Comment: But you can't do that to a list of functions

Comment: Second answer is about converting func not to numpy,its about tensorflow,i need to convert to tensor after using numpy,but i will think about converting np func to tensor

Answer (score 0):

To create a TensorFlow function from a numpy function, you should use `tf.py_func`:

> Wraps a python function and uses it as a TensorFlow op.

From the TensorFlow [API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func):

```
def my_func(x):
  # x will be a numpy array with the contents of the placeholder below
  return np.sinh(x)
inp = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
y = tf.py_func(my_func, [inp], tf.float32)
```

Comment: Thank you for help.
And what about function with 2 values?like sinh(x)+sinh(y)?

Comment: `y = tf.py_func(my_func, [inp1, inp2], tf.float32)` would just work fine.